# How to get information about events from Google calendar on Java, Android?

Tags: java, android

I need get information about events from calendar of my Android device, but I don't know how to do it. Give me an example please or give me a advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use oAuth : http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices.html

You can also use the Java tool: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html